# lambda to take `char` argument

Tags: c++, string, c++11, lambda

How I should define lambda to take `char` from `string iterator`? In the code below lambda `detect_bracket` has problem with input parameter `x`.

**I don't want to delete *ALL* brackets from the string, just at the beginning and at the end.**

```
auto detect_bracket = [](char* x){ return(')' == x || '(' == x);};

this->str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.begin(),
            detect_bracket)
);
this->str.erase(std::remove_if(str.back(), str.back(),
            detect_bracket)
);
```

Comment: `[](char x){ return(')' == x || '(' == x);}` isn't sufficient?

Comment: @101010 `/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_FIter std::remove_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate) [with _FIter = char; _Predicate = ExprContainer::removeBrackets()::__lambda0]’:
../src/CMEXPR.cpp:194:20:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:1150:25: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘char’)`

Comment: not `char*` but rather `char`.

Comment: [`str.back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back) returns a `char`, not an iterator to the first element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take `char` as the parameter type of the lambda with [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), since the signature of the predicate function is supposed to check the element directly.

```
auto detect_bracket = [](char x){ return(')' == x || '(' == x);};
this->str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
        detect_bracket)
);
```

Note `std::string::back()` won't work with `std::remove_if`. It will return a `char` and `std::remove_if` expects a range expressed by iterator.

And `str.begin(), str.begin()` is just an empty range, if you just want to remove element at the begin and end, you could

```
auto detect_bracket = [](char x){ return(')' == x || '(' == x);};
if (!this->str.empty()) {
    this->str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.begin() + 1, detect_bracket), str.begin() + 1);
}
if (!this->str.empty()) {
    this->str.erase(std::remove_if(str.end() - 1, str.end(), detect_bracket), str.end());
}
```

Note we need to specify the correct end iterator for `std::string::erase`, because `std::remove_if` will return an iterator even if it found nothing, and then the char will be erased wrongly.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/OYF16582)

Comment: `str.begin(), str.end()`

Comment: I don't want to delete *ALL* brackets from the string, just at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: @CronAcronis `str.begin(), str.begin()` is an empty range so it won't remove anything. You might want `str.begin(), str.begin() + 1`, and `str.rbegin(), str.rbegin() + 1`.

Comment: @songyuanyao you are wrong. It work just perfectly. Try.

Comment: @CronAcronis Note that `remove_if` will return an iterator anyway even if passed in an empty range. For `str.begin(), str.begin()` it will return `str.begin()`, and then `erase()` will erase the first char even it's not '(' or ')' at all. [Demo](http://rextester.com/GTIZ14490)

Comment: @songyuanyao i see, you are right! thx for the explanation and patience!

Comment: @CronAcronis It is true that my original code has bug too. Sorry for that. Now I've fixed them.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) is a function with the following signature:

> ```
> template< class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate >
> ForwardIt remove_if( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p );
> ```
>
> ---
>
> `p` - unary predicate which returns ​`true` if the element should be removed. 
>   The signature of the predicate function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> bool pred(const Type &a);
> ```
>
> The type `Type` must be such that an object of type `ForwardIt` can be
>   dereferenced and then implicitly converted to Type. ​

All you need is to change your function parameter from `char*` to `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `remove_if` and `erase` calls are anyway modifying/invalidating the `string`. Why not simply create a new `string`, and conditionally assign source string from 0th location or 1st location? And then `assign` till the last or second last character, *conditionally*?

```
string target;
target.assign(source.begin() + skip_if_bracket_at_begin, 
    source.end() - skip_if_bracket_at_end);
```